# How do you query database using a variable? Dynamic SQL...?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm wondering how to search a database table using a given variable or an array in the SQL query. I'm currently using Java and PostgreSQL and I want to do something like:

```
String word = "Apples";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = word;
```

or

```
token[0] = "Apples";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = token[0};
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

My eventual goal is simply to check the database to see if a word that a user has input is stored in the database and if it is then do something with that word.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html

Answer (score 3):

Use PrepareStatement like,

```
String word = "Apples";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
st.setString(1, word);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error message: error: cannot find symbol
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");

Comment: @Feenix: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html

Comment: Is it compile time exception or runtime? Did you import, `import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data in java end, do something like:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","name","pass");
  PreparedStatement updateemp = con.prepareStatement
  ("insert into emp values(?,?,?)");
  updateemp.setInt(1,23);
  updateemp.setString(2,"Roshan");
  updateemp.setString(3, "CEO");
  updateemp.executeUpdate();
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  String query = "select * from emp";
  ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

See full details :
[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm)